# Placeholder for date in sh script?

Tags: debian, sh

so I want to create an automated backup system for my server, I am thinking of cron jobs starting a script everyday, the problem is, the names of the zip files must be different, so in the sh script I need is:

> zip -r backup(date).zip daemon-data

What to place in (data), so I get it to write the date?

Answer (score 0):

[`date`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=date+%2B%27%25s%27) - print or set the system date and time

```sh
$ date +'%s'
1554144568
```

You can use eval command $() syntax:

```
$ zip -r backup$(date +'%s').zip daemon-data
```

Comment: If you want this in a crontab file, double the `%`s to escape them.

Comment: I am sorry for being so dumb, but what's the format for it, like DD-MM-YYYY or what